# Formatting ColdFusion code with Visual Studio Code

Tags: coldfusion

is anyone using Visual Studio Code? I'm trying to format the code with the command ALT+SHIFT+F  and after that it says: "There is no formatter for 'cfml' files installed." How can we format the ColdFusion code in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837342/auto-format-on-visual-studio-code-for-cfm-files.  If so, please delete your question as it is a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto Format on Visual Studio Code for .cfm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837342/auto-format-on-visual-studio-code-for-cfm-files)